# Why would it be necessary to perform two casts to a mutable raw pointer in a row?

Tags: pointers, casting, rust

When looking at [`unix-socket`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/unix-socket/blob/master/src/lib.rs), I came across this code:

```
let timeout = unsafe {
    let mut timeout: libc::timeval = mem::zeroed();
    let mut size = mem::size_of::<libc::timeval>() as libc::socklen_t;
    try!(cvt(libc::getsockopt(self.0,
                              libc::SOL_SOCKET,
                              kind,
                              &mut timeout as *mut _ as *mut _,
                              &mut size as *mut _ as *mut _)));
    timeout
};
```

I was curious about these lines in particular:

```
&mut timeout as *mut _ as *mut _,
&mut size as *mut _ as *mut _
```

Why is it necessary to perform two casts to a mutable raw pointer in a row? Why wouldn't it have been sufficient to only cast once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `timeout` for example corresponds to a [`*mut c_void`](http://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/fn.getsockopt.html) parameter:

```
pub unsafe extern fn getsockopt(sockfd: c_int, level: c_int, optname: c_int,
                                optval: *mut c_void, optlen: *mut socklen_t) -> c_int
```

The `timeout` in that file is defined as:

```
let mut timeout: libc::timeval = mem::zeroed();
```

So it's of type `libc::timeval`. Now let's consider:

```
&mut timeout as *mut _ as *mut _
```

First you have `&mut timeout` so that is of type `&mut libc::timeval`. Then you do `as *mut _` to coerce it to a raw mutable pointer of an inferred type, which in this case is the same type of `libc::timeval`, so the full type so far is: `*mut libc::timeval`, which doesn't match the parameter type `*mut c_void`. The final `as *mut _` again infers the target type, which is now the parameter type `*mut c_void`, so this finally coerces the `*mut libc::timeval` to a `*mut c_void`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks for clarifying! Follow-up question: does rust infer the the second conversion because of the signature of `getsockopt` or is is just that *every* pointer gets cast to `*mut c_void` if I do the conversion often enough? Even for an arbitrary original type, let's say `&mut Vec<i32>`?

Comment: Nah, thankfully not! That would be scary :S It's indeed because of the signature of `getsockopt`, specifically because the expression's position has that target type. The same would be the case e.g. if you were doing `let ptr: *mut c_void = &mut timeout as *mut _ as *mut _;`.

Comment: This casting can be made a little shorter: `&mut timeout as *mut _ as _` (notice the last `mut` was removed.